# How to loop a bash script once a file is added?

Tags: bash

At present I copy say 100 .ENC files and run this .sh file and it works and then it quits, however I then add another 100 .enc files to the and manually run the script.

My question is: is it possible to loop this script so regardless of how many .enc files it will just keep processing them?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: Decrypt files with ENC extension then deletes file
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.enc
do
    echo "Decrypt file - $f"
        bbfc_decrypt "$f" 
    echo "Deleting file"
        rm "$f" 
done
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want the script to run forever, and process every new file as it appears?  Or do you want to have the script run automatically whenever a new file is added?  Both approaches are possible, and both have their pitfalls and edge cases to worry about.

Comment: wrap your `for` loop with a `while` loop, i.e. `while true ; do for .... ; done ; sleep 60 ; done`

Comment: @WilliamPursell either will be good, I am trying to have the process automated as much as possible, so if it runs forever and process the files as it appears great, equally if it triggers the script when a new file appears that also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: Decrypt files with ENC extension then deletes file
shopt -s nullglob
while true; do
    for f in *.enc
    do
        echo "Decrypt file - $f"
        bbfc_decrypt "$f" 
        echo "Deleting file"
        rm "$f" 
    done
    sleep 1
done
```

Cleaner way, execute only if a new file appear:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder="." # The folder to listen
shopt -s nullglob

inotifywait -q -e create -m $folder |
while read -s -r directory event filename; do
    if [[ $filename == *'.enc' ]]; then
        echo "Decrypt file - $filename"
        bbfc_decrypt "$folder/$filename" 
        echo "Deleting file"
        rm "$folder/$filename"
    fi
done
```

To use inotifywait on Debian based systems, you need to install inotify-tools:

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki

Comment: Thank you Poka, sudo is not found as its a SunOS Solaris 10 box... I am however testing your suggestion for the "Shortest way" and I will let you know how it goes..

Comment: For Solaris, maybe the "Solaris File Event Notification" could replace inotify-tools: https://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/solaris-file-event-notification/